# Nested for loops to iterate between two strings

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I'd like to, using for loops, iterate through each string and output each character turn by turn.

```
String a = "apple";
String b = "class";

for (int i = 0;  i < a.length() ; i++) { // - 1 because 0 = 1
    System.out.print(a.charAt(i));
    for (int j = 0; j < b.length(); j ++) {
        System.out.print(b.charAt(j));
    }
}
```

I'm struggling with the inner loop.

At the moment my output is as followed:

```
AClasspClasspClasslClasseClass
```

However, I'd like to achieve the following:

```
acplpalses
```

***Extended Question:***

How about outputting one string in reverse while the other is outputted normally?

Current Attempt:

```
for (int i = a.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    System.out.println(a.charAt(i));
    for (int j = 0; j < b.length(); j ++) {
        System.out.println(b.charAt(j));
    }
}
```

However, this simply outputs as above, just with "Apple" in reverse order in the same format as previous:

```
eclasslclasspclasspclassaclass
```

Comment: May I know why you did change the accepted answer while the one you accepted covers 1 case and mine covers 4 cases including the one of the actual accepted answer ? ;)

Comment: @azro must have been a missclick :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need 2 loops as you take the same indice for both `Strings`

---

*Same Order :*

1. Simple same-size case **:**

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
       System.out.print(a.charAt(i));
       System.out.print(b.charAt(i));
   }
   ```
2. *Complex* different-size case **:**

   ```
   int minLength = Math.min(a.length(), b.length());
   for (int i = 0; i < minLength; i++) {
       System.out.print(a.charAt(i));
       System.out.print(b.charAt(i));
   }
   System.out.print(a.substring(minLength)); // prints the remaining if 'a' is longer
   System.out.print(b.substring(minLength)); // prints the remaining if 'b' is longer
   ```

---

*Different order :*

1. Simple same-size case **:**

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
       System.out.print(a.charAt(i));
       System.out.print(b.charAt(b.length() - i - 1));
   }
   ```
2. *Complex* different-size case **:**

   ```
   int minLength = Math.min(a.length(), b.length());
   for (int i = 0; i < minLength; i++) {
       System.out.print(a.charAt(i));
       System.out.print(b.charAt(b.length() - i - 1));
   }
   System.out.print(a.substring(minLength));
   System.out.print(new StringBuilder(b).reverse().substring(minLength));
   ```

Comment: Great! Really appreciate your time. Thanks.

Comment: @LearningToJava Remember that is you have nested loop, the second loop will execute for EACH value of the first one, that why you had several time the word `class` in your result

Comment: Okay, Thanks, That makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using Java 8 streams:

```
System.out.println(
    IntStream.range(0, Math.min(a.length(), b.length()))
        .mapToObj(i -> "" + a.charAt(i) + b.charAt(i))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(""))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

For the extended question-
Assuming both strings are of same size

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
    System.out.print(a.charAt(a.length()-1-i));
    System.out.print(b.charAt(i));
}
```